# Extension to complex numbers

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, extension-field

Is there an extension to the complex numbers in which $zz^* = i$ has a solution? (The star denotes conjugation.)

EDIT:

I'm mathematically ignorant, but I'm *guessing* such an extension can't be a Banach algebra because norms in Banach algebras are non-negative reals.

Comment: Well, conjugation is defined specifically within the realm of complex numbers, so your question is rather ill-defined.

Comment: @Kaj_H: Conjugation is also defined for two (successive) extensions of the complex numbers, namely quaternions and octonions. However, in both cases $xx^\ast$ is a non-negative real number.
(I don't know if the next extension, sedenions, also has a conjugation operator)

Comment: Why is my question so strongly demoted?

Comment: ^Ah, good point.

Comment: In case my last comment seems strange, I brought it up when my question had been demoted to -3.

Comment: Do you require this extension to be a field?  What about a definition over the quaternions?

Comment: A field would be nice, but not necessary.
Since asking this question I realized one would first need to know exactly what qualifies as a conjugate operator and what doesn't. I don't know the answer to that.
If you can make a definition over the quaternions work, great, but as with complex numbers, $qq^*$ in $\Bbb H$ gives a real number.

Comment: Under most circumstances, one might want or assume as self-evident that the conjugation works at least like transposition, i.e., that $(ab)^*=b^*a^*$. But then, $(zz^*)^*=(z^*)^*z^*$, and if the usual rules apply, double conjugation is the identity. Which would, in consequence, require that $i=i^*$ is fixed under conjugation.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think that $\sqrt{-1}$ is really $\sqrt{-1*1}$ which is a sort of **geometric mean** of 1 and -1.  So, the complex numbers enable us to calculate something which was inaccessible for certain numbers.  (Of course, the geometric mean is also defined for more than two terms, e.g. the cube root of three numbers.)

An extension to complex numbers that would be useful:

- would help us be capable of calculations on things are currently
  "inaccessible"
- may not necessarily add an extra dimension to the complex plane
- etc.